# JSF 2.0 file upload - walkthrough?

Tags: file, jsf, upload

I have looked around for a while looking for a complete guide for this. I've been working with JSF like 2 days now and am trying to make a page that will upload a pdf file to a server, putting its file path into a database along with other user-inputted text fields.

This is my form (so far)

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:outputText value="Name: " />
        <h:inputText id="name" size="40" value="#{resumeBean.name}" required="true"/> <br/>
        <h:outputText value="Position Sought: "/>
        <h:inputText id="position" size="40" value="#{resumeBean.position}" required="true"/> <br/>
        <h:outputText value="Date: " />
        <h:inputText id="date" size="40" value="#{resumeBean.date}" required="true" /> <br/>
        <h:outputText value="File to upload: " />
        <t:inputFileUpload value="#{bean.resume}" /> <br/>
        <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
        <h:messages />
    </h:form>
```

and this bean to handle the file

```
   package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String name, position, date;
    private String fileName;
    private UploadedFile resume;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setResume(UploadedFile resume) {
        this.fileName = resume.getName();
        this.resume = resume;
    }

    public UploadedFile getResume() {
        return resume;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void submit() throws IOException {
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(resume.getName());
        String contentType = resume.getContentType();
        byte[] bytes = resume.getBytes();

        // Now you can save bytes in DB (and also content type?)

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
            new FacesMessage(String.format("File '%s' of type '%s' successfully uploaded!", fileName, contentType)));
    }
}
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="timesheet2" version="3.0">
  <display-name></display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener> 
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class> 
  </listener> 
  <filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

but from here I have no idea how to continue, help please?
thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at this article http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html (Uploading files with JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0)

Comment: You've there pretty complete code. What exactly is the problem you're struggling with? You don't know how to save the file bytes on local disk file system or DB? That has got nothing to do with uploading files in JSF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BalusC has made a blog post about [File Uploading](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) by building a custom tag component, pure JSF based for JSF 2.0 and 2.1. Since JSF 2.2, there's a JSF component for file uploading: [`<h:inputFile>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/inputFile.html).

Also, you can look another implementations like [PrimeFaces FileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml) and [RichFaces FileUpload](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload).

Comment: The post of the blog is outdated content.

Comment: This was as fast as possible! :) Thanks. (I could also updated the answer, but it is yours, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Might I recommend the [PrimeFaces FileUploader](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf)?

Comment: Comments don't allow the provision of links. They should also be constructive... :-)

Comment: I do not know a good answer that is also a question. And yes, you can post link in comments, like @Daniel has done.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that. I also noticed how your answer is both Daniel's and mine.. ;-)

Comment: And RichFaces too! Don't forget about it, also I've posted my answer at the same time of Daniel's comment. Why is my answer like that? Because BalusC has a very good explanation on this matter, no need to add any piece of information to a good answer.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: Ever heard of a rhetorical question? (This comment may or may not be an example of one.)